# What does it mean to have a number of size $B$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, terminology

I have a really stupid question that I don't seem to know the answer to and have been too embarassed to ask. In some number theory papers, I encounter sums of the form $$\sum_{\substack{{x \asymp B}\\P(x) =0}}1$$ to count solutions "of size B" to some quadratic form $P$ (often $x \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ but let us ignore that for now). Alternately, I see statements like let us consider a set of $k$ $\textbf{primes of size $N\log N$}$.

In Vinogradov notation, if $f(x) \ll g(x)$ and $g(x)\ll f(x)$, we write $f(x) \asymp g(x)$, but what does it mean in this context?

For example, when is a prime of size $N\log N$? Vinogradov notation suggests that for a prime
$p \asymp N\log N$, there exist constants $C, C' >0$ such that
$$CN\log N\leq p \leq C'N\log N.$$

In the same vein, $x\asymp B$ should probably mean that there are such positive $k, k'$ such that
$kB\leq |x| \leq k'B$.

My question is: how small and big can these $C$, $C'$, $k$, $k'$ be?

Also, let $\mathcal{P} = \{p \textrm{ prime}: p \asymp N \log N\}$. What does the set $\mathcal{P}$ look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a good question, and the answer is that writing $x\asymp B$ under a sum **is sloppy notation without further clarification**. It can mean that $c_1 B<x<c_2 B$ for any fixed constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ (and then the sum will depend on those constants), or it can mean the same for some constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ fixed explicitly at the beginning of the paper. For example, the author might say in the notation section that $x\asymp B$ will mean $B<x<2B$, although some authors would denote this relation by $x\sim B$ to distinguish it from $x\asymp B$.

Comment: Thank you very much! For example, in this paper (https://www.jstor.org/stable/43973030), the authors consider a set $\mathcal{P}$ of $P$ primes of size $P\log P$. If they mean that each such prime is between $P\log P$ and $2P \log P$, then can we fit in $P$ primes in this interval? It seems that by the PNT, one can do at most $2P\log P/ \log (2P \log P)$ which is $<P$ for large enough $P$.

Comment: In addition, in general, if $CP\log P<p<C'P\log P$, then if  I take $C= \log P$, then doesn't $p$ cease to be of size $P\log P$? How big can my $C$ really be? Maybe there is something I do not understand here.

Comment: @user19094093 $2P\log P/\log (2P\log P)$ is asymptotically $2P$ (so it exceeds $1.99P$ for $P$ large). The number of primes between $P\log P$ and $2P\log P$ is asymptotically $P$, but the actual number is slightly less than $P$ for $P>10^4$ (say). See my answer at https://mathoverflow.net/q/435028 Regarding your last question, you cannot take $C=\log P$ as it grows with $P$. A constant means a quantity that does not change (like $10^{100}$). For further questions, please open a new post.

Comment: Thanks so much!